# How to check a checkbox with boolean values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So the HTML spec says that you should add a `checked` attribute to the `<input type="checkbox">` tag to mark it as checked. But I only have a boolean `true` or `false` value.

As by design, I can't add any logic to the boolean value before it get parsed to html :(. 
Is it possible to check a Checkbox with a Boolean value on load just with html or js? I tried the following, but the `onload` seem not to trigger:

```
<input type="checkbox" onload="javascript:this.checked=true" />
```

I know that I can do something like this in jQuery:

```
$("[checked='false']").prop('checked',false)
```

I am looking for an elegant way to solve it. This must parse the whole DOM-Tree and would slow down my page.

---

Edit (trying to explain):

In my company there exist a application that does the following by design:

```
 <input type="checkbox" checked="%IsValide%" >
```

The Server than automatically replaces the `%IsValide%` var with a database value. Here true or false. But then the checkbox is always checked, even if the value is false. I am aware that this is because of the design of html5: checked="true" and checked="false" will marke the checkbox always as checked.

Now I'am searching for a solution to use the true or false value from `%IsValide%` to check the box correctly with javascript (or even better, with html.). I can use the `%IsValide%` at any position in the html tag. For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" onload="javascript:this.checked=%IsValide%" />
```

But I **can not** add logic before it get parsed to HTML like this:

```
if(%IsValide%) {
 %IsValide%="checked";
}
else {
 %IsValide%="";
}
```

Comment: So `<input type="checkbox" checked />` doesn't work for you?

Comment: It works, but I can't use it because I am getting a boolean value from a database and I can not add logic (e.g. `(checkVar? "checked" : "")`) before.

Comment: Sorry but I'm still not clear on what the issue/question is.

Comment: `.attr("checked",true)`

Comment: Whatever you're getting from the database is on the server-side, right? Then you can use server-side logic.

Comment: You can just do it by plain js if you want: `document.getElementById("input").checked = !document.getElementById("input").checked;` this would toggle a checkbox with id `input`

Comment: Why can't you 'add logic'? Why have you tagged this question with JavaScript/jQuery if you *can't use it* to do something logical like this?

Comment: "It works, but I can't use it because I am getting a boolean value from a database and I can not add logic" 

"Adding logic" is kind of a fundamental thing about programming. :) Can you explain more what exactly is going on here? We're all scratching our heads.

Comment: Seeing as how checked is a boolean attribute, meaning its mere presence or absence determines the value, it looks like your company's application needs an update since it's not setting it properly. But I digress...

Comment: @aquinas "add logic **before**". I sholud have said: on the server side. I am searching for a solution on the client side.

Comment: I'm curious to know what replaces %IsValid% with true? What is your server side language?

Comment: @aquinas It's a funny (ironical) layout engine someone designed on it's own  which I have selected for me. It's like Razor but really bad. Basically it's an ASP-Page with UserControls where you can put Database-Values inside the Controls with this syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I'm trying to understand what your asking. I'm thinking that you could accomplish it with some simple javascript:

```
document.getElementById("yourCheckBoxId").checked = false; //this case it sets checked to false you can also do true
```

to check it on page load:

```
<body onload='document.getElementById("yourCheckBoxId").checked = true;'>
```

or avoid the onload attribute for body for checking it do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="yourCheckBoxId" checked>
```

Then you just change it with javascript.

My other guess is that your wanting to change the value of the checkbox? Are you? Post a comment below my answer saying that I didn't understand what you are asking. Hope this helps! Here is my reference source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Comment: I was about to post pretty much the same Answer as this one.  However, there is the possibility that the web page will have more than one checkbox on it.  So, each one needs a different `id`, but the `body` tag's `onload` JavaScript text also needs different Server-variable identifiers, like this: `"onload=document.getElementById('cb01').checked=%IsValide1%;document.getElementById('cb02').checked=%IsValide2%;"`, etc.

Comment: thanks I will take a look at that. However you could just do a loop perhaps and create and access the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If your company's application sets `checked="true"` or `checked="false"` as you can see, this will not matter since `checked` is a boolean attribute and "the presence of this Boolean attribute indicates that the control is selected by default", and the checkbox will always be checked.

This should fix it:

```
$('input[checked="false"]').prop('checked',false)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9bnggtyx/)**

Comment: As I said not exactly what I am searching for (because need to search over the whole DOM) but when there is no other way to go I will use this.

Comment: What do you mean by "search over the whole DOM"?

Comment: $('input[checked="false"]') this will search for every input element on the page. So the browser JS engine will go over the whole DOM-Tree and search for it. While for example this `<input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:this.checked=true" />` doesn't need to search over the tree, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, your inline JS example will only execute on that one element while the jQuery will select all inputs on the page with checked=false (not all input elements however). But unless you have thousands of checkboxes I doubt you'd even notice a performance hit by using the jQuery (or plain vanilla JS equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

I think ultimately you're going about this the wrong way, but if I had *no other option* like you're saying, I think the best you'll end up with (performance wise) would be to add a class to your input (true or false)

```
<input type="checkbox" class="tocheck-true"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="tocheck-false"></input>
```

and then look for that class:

```
$("input.tocheck-true").prop("checked",true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mu81yz7y/

Because we're searching only for inputs that have that css class, this should perform very well.

But, again, this seems like a complete hack. If you're asking "how can I use duct tape to secure the engine to the body of my car," maybe you should stop to see if you should even be *asking* that question. :)